# "Its ethos of ~ was now 'something to aspire to.'"

Tags: tense

This is from [a *New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/18/arts/music/dad-rock.html).

> But in the past decade or so, Mitchum realized, the “dad rock” tag has become much less derisive than it was when he first used it. Its ethos of “middle-age contentment” and just liking what you like **was** now “something to aspire to.” “Calling a band dad-rock in 2019,” he concluded, “is just as likely to be a defiant re-appropriation of a hipster insult.”

I wonder why past tense is used in the part in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paragraph seems to be written generally in the past tense:

- In the first sentence, "realized" is in the past tense.
- In the second sentence, "was" is in the past tense.
- In the third sentence, "concluded" is in the past tense.

The only exception is "has become" in the first sentence. That is acceptable because it refers to an action that began in the past and is continuing into the present; the present perfect is thus appropriate there.

Comment: Thank you very much.